# When upgrading to an SSD from HDD, can swap the disks then copy files?

Tags: windows, ssd, oem

I am about to move from an HDD to an SSD.

Rather than copy across the current installation (Windows 10 OEM) using a tool, can I do the following?

1. backup anything of importance
2. create Windows installation media [using the official route](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)
3. remove the HDD and install the SSD
4. install Windows 10 OEM
5. copy any files that I forgot about from the old hard drive in step 1

I would assume that this would look like the equivalent of replacing a crashed hard drive from the point of view of Microsoft.

Is there any reason why this is a bad idea? I have already reinstalled this OEM edition on the same hardware once before, but that was onto the same disk.

Comment: Unless there's any software you don't have the key/serial info for anymore, you can do it that way. Its the method I would choose as its generally faster especially if the new ssd is high spec. For example I can install W10 in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

That's called "Disaster Recovery (DR)". If you make backups with a software that advertises "Bare Metal Restore (BMR)" it will do exactly what you want. Usually, the backup software makes a recovery image. You boot to their recovery environment and perform the bare metal restore that way. This skips the "install windows" step. It will restore the system to the exact state it was in at the time of backup in one step.